# Update or Insert new data in nested array MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, mongodb-query, insert-update

I'm using Node JS with Mongoose fyi. Given I've something like this:-

```
let people = [
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "Person 1",
        "pets": [
            {
                "_id": 1,
                "name": "Tom",
                "category": "cat",
                "favFood": [
                    {
                        "_id": 1,
                        "name": "steamed fish"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": 2,
                "name": "Jerry",
                "category": "mouse",
                "favFood": [
                    {
                        "_id": 1,
                        "name": "cheese"
                    }
                ] 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Right now I know how to `insert` new `pet` data *like shown below*:-

```
// new Pet Data to INSERT
let newPetData = {
    name: "Butch",
    category: "dog",
    favFood: [
        {
            name: "bone"
        }
    ]    
}

// INSERT new data in DB
People.updateOne(
    // push into the sub-documents - pets
    { $push: { pets: newPetData } },
    (err, success) => {
        if(err) res.json({ message: `Unsuccessful!`, report: err })
        else res.json({ message: `Successful!`, report: success })
    }
)
```

But how can I insert new `favFood` data of a `pet` if I have their `id` **(id of the pet)**?

```
let petID = 1 // this is the ID of pet named Tom

// this is a new favorite food of Tom to INSERT
let newFavFood = {
    name: "fried fish"
}

// code to INSERT new favorite food of Tom (THIS DOES NOT WORK!)
People.updateOne(
    { "_id": petID } // id of pet 'Tom'
    { $push: { favFood: newFavFood } }, // push into the sub-documents - favFood
    (err, success) => {
        if(err) res.json({ message: `Unsuccessful!`, report: err })
        else res.json({ message: `Successful!`, report: success })
    }
)
```

The above code does not work. I thought that if I specify the `id` of a pet like show above `{ "_id": petID }` would yield what I want. Even though it returns a `message` of `Successful!`. But still **no new record added** to the **db** itself. The result I'm seeking of would be *something shown below*:-

```
let people = [
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "Person 1",
        "pets": [
            {
                "_id": 1,
                "name": "Tom",
                "category": "cat",
                "favFood": [
                    {
                        "_id": 1,
                        "name": "steamed fish"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": 2, 
                        "name": "fried fish" // this is the new data inserted
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": 2,
                "name": "Jerry",
                "category": "mouse",
                "favFood": [
                    {
                        "_id": 1,
                        "name": "cheese"
                    }
                ] 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

is there any other way I can do this? Do I have to implement `$elemMatch` in this? If so, how can I do that here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query part matches documents, not elements, so `{ "_id": petID }` is matching the person's _id.  To match the pet's, use dotted notation like `{ "pets._id": petID }`

Then use the positional operator `$` to reference the first array element that matched the query part:

```
.updateOne(
    { "pets._id": petID },
    { $push: { "pets.$.favFood": newFavFood }}
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'using positional operator `$` to reference the **first array element** that matched the query part'?

Comment: In the example, the query part `{ "pets._id": petID }` matches the _id field of an element of the `pets` array.  In the update part `pets.$` refers to the first element in the `pets` array that satisfied the query part.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update

Comment: It said it here in the documentation you just gave me that if I were to have one more nested array that comes after `favFood` array like for example: `favFood [{ _id: 1, name: Fried fish, Nutrition: [{ _id: 1, name: Vit A }, { _id: 1, name: Vit B }] }]`. I **added** new array called `Nutrition` inside `favFood` array. So I can't use this method if I want to `push` new `data` to `Nutrition` array? Do you have any documentation I can refer to for this kind of operation?

Comment: In that case, you will need to use [array filters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#specify-arrayfilters-for-array-update-operations), and specify a filter for each array